# Быстрое деление многочлена на многочлен

Tags: алгоритм, математика, деление, полином

Требуется литература или любая другая информация в данном вопросе. В частности, алгоритм деления многочлена на многочлен ниже квадратичного порядка (обычный уголок не подходит). Деление многочлена на многочлен должно просчитывать частное и остаток от деления.

Comment: https://dxdy.ru/topic72827.html Сложно что ли?

Comment: Вопрос был к людям, которые уже сталкивались с этой проблемой и подходил к её решению. Пару первых ссылок в гугле основательной информации не дали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что означает `алгоритм деления многочлена на многочлен ниже квадратичного порядка` - на бином `x-a`? Для этого есть процедура "synthetic division"

```
 //деление полинома, коэффициенты которого хранятся в массиве CC[]
 //на (x - tx)
 //источник - Numerical Recipes in C, chapter 5 
var
   CC: array of Double;
   rem, temp, tx: double;
   n, i: integer;
 begin
   CC := [5, 3, 2];   //2x^2+3x+5
   n := Length(CC) - 1;
   tx := 1;           //x-1

   rem := CC[n];
   CC[n] := 0;
   for i := n - 1 downto 0 do
   begin
     temp := CC[i];
     CC[i] := rem;
     rem := temp + rem * tx;
   end;


   Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('[%2.0f, %2.0f, %2.0f], rem = %2.0f',[CC[0], CC[1], CC[2], rem]));
   //теперь степень полинома понижена на единицу
   //коэффициенты в том же CC[], числовой остаток в rem

 >> [ 5,  2,  0], rem = 10
 2x^2+3x+5 = (2x+5)*(x-1) + 10
```

В указанной книге есть и деление на полином произвольной степени `poldiv` с получением также коэффициентов полинома-остатка. С++ вариант (`u / v`, так что `u = v * q + r`)

```
void NR::poldiv(Vec_I_DP &u, Vec_I_DP &v, Vec_O_DP &q, Vec_O_DP &r)
{
        int k,j;

        int n=u.size()-1;
        int nv=v.size()-1;
        for (j=0;j<=n;j++) {
                r[j]=u[j];
                q[j]=0.0;
        }
        for (k=n-nv;k>=0;k--) {
                q[k]=r[nv+k]/v[nv];
                for (j=nv+k-1;j>=k;j--) r[j] -= q[k]*v[j-k];
        }
        for (j=nv;j<=n;j++) r[j]=0.0;
}
```

Для реализации более быстрого алгоритма потребуется использование FFT (быстрое преобразование Фурье). Умножение полиномов (это достаточно популярный алгоритм) с его применением делается через свертку (convolution), а деление - через деконволюцию (deconvolution).
[Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deconv.html)
[Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html)

Comment: x - a - бином. Нет. Деление полином на полином, а не деление полинома на бином. Деление полинома на бином по схеме Горнера. А требуется деление полинома на полином с частным и остатком.

Comment: Ну так я же указал общедоступную книгу, в которой это есть. Добавил код.

Comment: Данный алгоритм уже реализовывал. Он имеет квадратичную сложность. Интересует именно линейно-логарифмическая. За книгу спасибо, гляну.

Comment: Тогда, видимо, через FFT нужно (через [deconvolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deconv.html), [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html))